# Are electrical wires Muktzeh?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, muktzeh

Are electrical wires *Muktzeh*? For example, I keep a few chargers for my mobile devices on my desk.

If so, what category of *Muktzeh* do they go under?

Answer (score 1):

They are Muktzeh machmas Melucha just like batteries and telephones which are Ussor to play around with. They can be moved though if you need their place or if you need them for other uses. see OC siman 308 sif 3.

Comment: perhaps they are muktzah machmas chisaron kis, and therefore, can't be moved at all.

Comment: yeah it went through my mind. But the Gedarim for MMC are not so clear so i avoided the subject. I leave this up to your Rabbi

Comment: Can you provide a source that batteries and telephones are MMC? And maybe wires are different?